# Why is my Keyboard only appearing on TextInput.focus() if I didn't already have it open?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm making a React Native App, testing on Android, with Text Inputs that are sent off to a Validation Endpoint to be validated. It's come through that we want to autoFocus the input if we have an error.

So, I've tried a few different ways, each works equally well, but basically, if I call `field.focus()` and the keyboard is closed, then the field is focused, and the keyboard pops up. If I do it and the keyboard is open, the keyboard closes, but does not open again, but the TextInput does get focus.

Any Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it happens (maybe it's a device bug). But you can `dismiss` keyboard with `Keyboard.dismiss()` when you send to validation endpoint and if there was an error, focus again on textinput